# Using Lodash mapKeys in react component triggering error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I don't understand why I can use `Object.keys` with `.map()` in a component but not the `mapKeys` from lodash.

```
<ul>
    {/* Working */}
    {Object.keys(this.props.departments).map(key => this._renderDepartments(key, this.props.departments[key]))}

    {/* Not working */}
    {mapKeys(this.props.departments, (hash, department ) => {return this._renderDepartments(hash, department);})}
</ul>
```

Error generated by react when using Lodash from example

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @psilocybin I now understand that this was not the correct solution for my needs in react. The Lodash function was created to manipulate objects and **always** return a new object.

I solved my issue by creating a helper function which I can use throughout my code.

**mapObject function**

```
export default (object, callback) => {
    return Object.keys(object || {}).map(key => {return callback(key, object[key]);});
};
```

**Usage**

```
<ul className="DEPARTMENTPICKER_departments">
    {mapObject(this.props.departments, (hash, department) => this._renderDepartments(hash, department))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

_.mapKeys takes an object and a function as parameters. The callback passes in the value as param 1 and the key as param 2. For example:

```
const mapped = _.mapKeys({ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, (value, key) => {
  return key + value;
});

console.log(mapped); // { 'a1': 1, 'b2': 2 }
```

Remember to *return* the value from the [mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys) callback. This will alter the keys in the returned object.

I think you've just misunderstood what mapKeys does -- it manipulates the key value and returns the object with the string returned within the callback which doesn't seem like what you're after. Stick with `Object.keys().map()`.

Comment: Even with `{mapKeys(this.props.departments, (department, hash) => {return this._renderDepartments(hash, department);})}` I get the error message

Comment: Your return value will return an object with a different *key* (with whatever you return in mapKeys callback) as can be seen in my example. Think about this and perhaps log out the value mapKeys gives you - check this is in the format your _renderDepartments function is expecting - mapKeys may not be what you're after as it *alters* the keys of an object.

Comment: Logged the values received by `this._renderDepartments` but seems fine. Can it be that it iterates over the object and after it is done automatically returns an object no matter what?

Comment: Yes, _.mapKeys will always return an object with the *new* mapped key - That may be the issue. Why not just use map?

Comment: Because it comes as an object and you can't use map for object. Trying to find the most simple way to map over an object. Ideas?

Comment: Using `Object.keys(obj)` is a popular pattern for mapping over an object as it gives you the key which in turn allows access to the value in the object (`obj[key]`) and I'd say it's the most simple way! :)

Comment: @NealVDV, I've updated my initial answer to explain exactly why _.mapKeys isn't working for this.

Comment: Now I understand that it was not what I needed! See my answer for the solution. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @NealVDV If you could mark this as the accepted answer, it will be useful to other SO users with similar queries about map / mapKeys

Answer (score 0):

According to the [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#mapKeys) the `_.mapkeys` function should look like this:

```
_.mapKeys(hash, => (value, key) {
  return key + value;
});
```

Where `Object.keys` returns an array of keys that you iterate over.

In your specific case the code should be something like:

```
<ul>
{values(mapKeys(this.props.departments, (department, hash) => 
  {
    return this._renderDepartments(hash, department);
  }))
}
</ul>
```

Comment: The mapkeys function looks like it should then right? mapKeys(object, (key, value) is exactly what I have. And why does mapKeys not behave in the same as iterating over an array?

Comment: try value, key not key,value

Comment: Even with that changed still the same error message, can it be that it returns an object for some reason?

Comment: Ah, looks like our second func function was not explicitly returning anything

Comment: Yeah, just re-read the docs, it returns an object with `{key: mappedVal}`. You might need to prepend `_.values()` to get the array of values from the object.